# check numeric value of a datagrdiview cell value?

Tags: c#

In my project, I have a datagridview with some columns, one of the columns have a numeric value. I want to perform a check for this cell value but it gives me an error

> string was not in a correct value.

this is my code:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow rw in dgv_student_update.Rows)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dgv_student_update.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(rw.Cells[3].Value) == 4)
        {
            sc.archive_student(dgv_student_update.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString(),last_year + " - " + current_year,Convert.ToInt32(dgv_student_update.Rows[i].Cells[1].value));
        }
    }
}
```

can anyone help please?

Comment: what is in the Value, when you watch it while debugging?

Comment: Use .Value instead of .Value.ToString().  No need to convert to integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Func<DataGridViewRow, int, int> cellValue = (row, i) => { 
   int.TryParse(row.Cells[i].Value + "", out i); return i; }; // returns 0 if TryParse fails

foreach (DataGridViewRow rw in dgv_student_update.Rows)
    if (cellValue(rw, 3) == 4)
        sc.archive_student(rw.Cells[2].Value.ToString(), 
        last_year + " - " + current_year, cellValue(rw, 1));
```

Comment: thank you i use your code it help me but i see all times it return the same value i have cellValue(rw, 3) == 4 in datagridview but it does not check it?

Comment: maybe try `if ( rw.Cells[3].Value.ToString().Trim() == "4" )` instead?

Answer (score 0):

It's just a matter of proper null and value checking. You cannot assume everything has a value and it is in the format you expect. First make sure the cell has a value. Then make sure the value can be converted to an integer. Follow this advice for your update as well, you are likely to hit the same kind of problem calling `archive_student`.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < dgv_student_update.Rows.Count; i++)
 {
     if(rw.Cells[3].Value != null)
     {
         string strCell3 = rw.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
         int intCell3 = 0;
         if(int.TryParse(strCell3, out intCell3))
         { 
            if (intCell3 == 4)
            {
                sc.archive_student(dgv_student_update.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString(),last_year + " - " + current_year,Convert.ToInt32(dgv_student_update.Rows[i].Cells[1].value));
            }       
         } 
         else
         {
            //you decide what to do if its not an integer value
         }  
     }  
     else
     {
         //you decide what to do if cell has no value
     }     
  }
```